# How do I reference Build.VERSION_CODES in my build.gradle file?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My build.gradle file contains this line:

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

I would prefer it to be like this:

```
targetSdkVersion Build.VERSION_CODES.o
```

Is that possible?  It would seem much cleaner/safer, but this syntax doesn't work.

Comment: `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` is a static final int so everywhere you use to it actually compiles to `26`. Everybody knows O is 26. 26 is shorter to write. Why would you prefer the longer over shorter especially if they're both constants and not variables? /// If you defined `ext.myTargetSdkVersion = 26` and decided to upgrade that later it's perfectly fine. But I see no point in your current way.

Comment: The target SDK version appears in multiple projects (for us) that must be in sync, otherwise lint will error out.  Add to that 'compileSdkVersion' must also match for the same reasons.  It would be nice to define this in one place for all usage instances.  It's better programming practice to define a constant than reference a literal in multiple places.  Better still is using a constant that the framework/sdk has already defined.

Comment: Down votes? For what?

Answer (score 2):

> The target SDK version appears in multiple projects [...] It would be nice to define this in one place for all usage instances

So we're talking about defining project-wide accessible build time values.

Put this in your *root project* `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 17
    targetSdkVersion = 26

    supportLibVersion = "26.0.0"
    playServicesVersion = "10.2.6"
}
```

And now you can reference these values in your module `build.gradle` like so:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$playServicesVersion"
    // ...
}

// ...
```

*I think* you can even omit the `rootProject.ext.` prefix as long the result name does not conflict with a DSL member name.

In Groovy you can use variables in strings as long as you use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, this is similar to what we did. I was just wondering if there were a way to improve upon it by utilizing values already defined by the platform.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that possible?

No, sorry. `Build` is a Java class that exists in the Android framework. It is not available to Gradle.

Comment: I thought you could reference it as 'android.Build.etc.'?

Comment: @Bungles: In an Android app, yes. In a Gradle script, no, AFAIK.

Comment: It would require adding Android SDK to buildscript classpath and quite frankly there's no point. That value is never going to change for sake of backwards compatibility so using `26` is perfectly valid.